# Surface integrals and Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When do we need to use the Jacobian for surface integrals? I'm asking because when you parametrize a surface $S\in \mathbb{R}^3$ then surely there is no need to change coordinates (essentially parametrising again) to find a simple integral. Can anyone give me an instance where the intial parametrisation does not give a 'simple' enough integral. For example:

> Calculate the flux of $\textbf{v}=x\textbf{i}+y\textbf{j}+z\textbf{k}$ out of the surface $S$ where $S$ is the portion of the elliptic paraboloid $z= 9-(x^2+y^2)$ for which $z\geq 0$

Parametrising $\textbf{t}(r,\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} r\cos{\theta} \\ r\sin{\theta} \\ 9-r^2 \end{pmatrix}$. We find the normal as $$\textbf{N}(r,\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} 2r^2\cos{\theta} \\ 2r^2\sin{\theta} \\ r \end{pmatrix}$$ Therefore the integral becomes: $$\iint_\Omega r^3+9r \;drd\theta$$ Now I'm not quite sure of the limits for the parametrised surface $\Omega$. I'd say they are $r:[0,3]$ and $\theta:[0,2\pi]$. This then gives and answer of $$\frac{243\pi}{2}$$ Is this right? And when would I need the Jacobian? That example (provided I've done it right) didn't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. The Jacobian is "hidden" in your choice of normal vector. Using subscripts to denote partial derivatives, you've used
$$
\mathbf{N}(r, \theta)
  = \mathbf{t}_{r} \times \mathbf{t}_{\theta}
  = \frac{\mathbf{t}_{r} \times \mathbf{t}_{\theta}}
         {\|\mathbf{t}_{r} \times \mathbf{t}_{\theta}\|}
   \cdot \|\mathbf{t}_{r} \times \mathbf{t}_{\theta}\|.
$$

If you had used a *unit* normal field $\mathbf{n}(r, \theta)$ to express the integrand $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{n}$, the Jacobian factor $\|\mathbf{t}_{r} \times \mathbf{t}_{\theta}\|$ would have had to be included manually.